# CONCAT function in PGAdmin4

Tags: sql, concatenation

Write a query that returns a new field called name_date that combines the name and date fields with the labels 'name:' and 'date:'. Your first row should look like this:

Hint: Use the CONCAT() function that you learned about to combine the labels with the field names.

name: Harrison Jonson; date: 2011-03-16
As a reminder, the fields you'll be working with are as follows:

created_at (date)
name (string)
address (string)
state (string)
zipcode (integer)
user_id (integer)

Here is what I wrote. What am I doing wrong?

SELECT name, created_at
CONCAT (name,':',name,';',date,':',created_at) AS "name_date";
FROM purchases;

Comment: It potentially can be the double semi-colon, try:
SELECT name, created_at CONCAT (name,':',name,';',date,':',created_at) AS "name_date" FROM purchases;

Answer (score 0):

I've been a SQL guy for almost 20 years and I struggled with your exact question some years ago. Clifford is correct about the additional semi-colon. But there is another issue with the postgres CONCACT function (which you might not see on all DBMS's).

CONCAT on postgres will only take two fields:

So if you tried this, it should work

```
SELECT CONCAT(name, date) AS "something" FROM purchases
```

But if you tried this, it shouldn't work, as I added a third field.

```
SELECT CONCAT(name, date, created_at) AS "something" FROM purchases
```

The way around this is to use the old double pipe method.

```
SELECT (name ||':'||name ||';'||date ||':'||created_at) AS name_date FROM purchases;
```

Let me know if you're still having issues.